# Groovy script to fetch a particular tag in the SOAP respone

Tags: groovy

I am working on an automation and my requirement says to fetch a particular tag in the response from SOAP when we hit a webservice and based on it mark the Response as passed or failed. If someone could help me with this snippet it would of great help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Where's an example soap response? And what have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)